# Unboxing for dynamic type

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, clr, value-type

Consider the following code:

```
public class Foo1
{
    public dynamic dowork()
    {
        return 10;
    }        
}
```

And in my `Main` , I call like:

```
int i = new Foo1().dowork();
```

The return value is 10. My question is why no `Unboxing` is required here?But in `watch` I've verified the `Return Type` of `dowork` is `System.Object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *is* unboxing - but it's doing it implicitly. There's an implicit conversion from any `dynamic` expression to any type. The exact conversion performed will depend on the execution-time type of the value.

From section 6.1.8 of the C# 5 specification:

> An implicit dynamic conversion exists from an expression of type `dynamic` to any type `T`. The conversion is dynamically bound (§7.2.2), which means that an implicit conversion will be sought at run-time from the run-time type of the expression to `T`. If no conversion is found, a run-time exception is thrown.

(There's a slight nuance here in that it's a conversion from any *expression* of type `dynamic` rather than a conversion from the `dynamic` type itself. That avoids some conversion loops which would cause issues elsewhere in the spec.)