# When accessing value-type properties of an object stored in a dynamic, does it cause boxing of those properties' values?

Tags: c#, dynamic, casting, boxing

Consider the following code...

```
public class ValueHolder<T>
{
    public T HeldValue{ get; set; }
}
```

When assigning x here, there is of course no boxing.

```
var intValueHolder = new ValueHolder<int>(){ HeldValue = 44 };
int x = intValueHolder.HeldValue;
```

But what about in this case where ValueHolder is stored in a dynamic? Is there boxing when assigning HeldValue to y?

```
dynamic dynamicValueHolder = new ValueHolder<int>(){ HeldValue = 44 };
int y = dynamicValueHolder.HeldValue;
```

I'm not sure exactly what the mechanism for dynamic *member* resolution is so I'm not sure how to check this.

**Note**

I am *not* storing a value-type in the dynamic, so examples like this...

```
dynamic x = 44; // 44 is boxed
```

...is not what I'm asking. In my example I'm storing an object in the dynamic so no boxing is needed there, but when I then access a value-type property on that object, is *that value-type property* boxed? Hopefully that clears up what I'm after here.

Comment: I don't believe it does. For someone more well-versed in IL, the output is here: http://pastebin.com/At9qhBWB (includes the difference between using `dynamic` as opposed to just `var`/`ValueHolder<int>`)

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31675973/unboxing-for-dynamic-type

Comment: Not a duplicate.  In that case a value-type is being passed directly through the dynamic which will cause boxing. Again, I am not asking that.  I am ***accessing a value-type property*** on an ***object stored in a dynamic***. Again, please review the code.  Hope this clarifies things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quote from [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/Dd264741%28v=VS.120%29.aspx) msdn document:

*" Type dynamic behaves like type object in most circumstances. However, operations that contain expressions of type dynamic are not resolved or type checked by the compiler. The compiler packages together information about the operation, and that information is later used to evaluate the operation at run time. As part of the process, variables of type dynamic are compiled into variables of type object. Therefore, type dynamic exists only at compile time, not at run time. "*

So

```
dynamic dynamicValueHolder = new ValueHolder<int>(){ HeldValue = 44 };
```

won't deal with boxing.

But dynamic is compiled like object and object is a reference type. When a refernce type is created, it can contain value type properties and those properties are stored on the heap because are part of the reference type (for more infos look at [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/csharp_memory01122006130034PM/csharp_memory.aspx) c-sharpcorner article. 
Then

```
int y = dynamicValueHolder.HeldValue;
```

implies unboxing.

Comment: Best answer. References the docs and has good explanation, including the bit about value types on an object also being stored on the heap, not the stack.  That I knew and wasn't part of the question, but it's good for others to read here.  The part of the question I did have, you answered perfectly.  Thanks.